# How to implement advanced notification with reply button (and customisation)

Tags: macos, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification, osx-yosemite

We want to make a native application using Apple push notification. We want to make a native application using Apple push notification. The problem is we want to custom the system notification when users hover on it. We notice that Skype can show the Reply button when you hover on its notification [image: Skype Notification].
Does anyone know how to create a notification like Skype does?
We'd also like to be able to make a couple of other modifications as well:

1. Show a different notification on hover.
2. Show a different notification on hover, preferably with a custom view, possibly including an image or webview?

Thanks.

**Update:**

I found that Skype don't use APNS to push new message (when Skype doesn't run, you won't see the notification when a new message arrive). The notification on the screen is a local notification. So, in my case which using remote notification, I ignore the `alert` key of remote notification payload and when the app receives a remote notification, it will remove this notification from `Notification Center` and push a new local notification. Here is the code:

```
func application(application: NSApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    println(userInfo)
    // remove the remote one
    let deliveredNotifications = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().deliveredNotifications
    if let lastRemoteNotif = deliveredNotifications.last as? NSUserNotification {
        NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().removeDeliveredNotification(lastRemoteNotif)
    }

    // push another local notification
    let localNotif =  NSUserNotification()
    localNotif.title = ""
    localNotif.deliveryDate = NSDate()
    localNotif.title = "CeillingNinja"
    localNotif.subtitle = "This is local notification"
    localNotif.informativeText = "Some text"
    localNotif.contentImage = NSImage(named: "Status")
    NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().deliverNotification(localNotif)
}
```

But when the app isn't running, user will see an empty notification in `Notification Center`. I still stuck at that point!

Comment: Using what language? In what context? Web app? native app? from a server using apple's push infrastructure? You'll need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Thanks for having a look @suranyami

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yep. But it's too long ago. I really don't remember the solution :)